# How to log failed script output to a different file while running db2cmd

Tags: sql, database, db2

We are running scripts using `db2cmd -vtf scriptfile -l logfile...`

All successfull and failed info is going to the same logfile.

We are executing a file which contains 500 script files, and I want only failed scripts to send output to a different log file.

Comment: Check the DB2 CLP (command line processor) exit code and rename the log file if it is not 0.

Comment: That doesn't solve their issue. They only want the errors in another file.

Comment: How can you be sure that a failed statement does not block subsequent calls? What I propose is to use the -s option, in order to stop the execution in order to correct the script, by showing as last message the first error.

Comment: You can use awk by merging command and SQLcode in the same line; after that you just filter the SQLcodes that mean error for you.

Comment: @AngocA ... we are using windows machine...is there any way to do this using batch script

Comment: I think there is an equivalent command in powershell. You need to merge all text lines between blank lines.  After that you can use the equivalent to find in cmd

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following option:

```
db2cmd -vtf scriptfile -l logfile -z errorFile
```

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0010410.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.1.0%2F3-5-2-0-2

Comment: tried with this but dont have luck...it includes DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully. statements als0, but i want to include only failed script info